# Taylor Theorem expansion and error question

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I have a problem were it says to use the Taylor theorem to show

> $$(1+x)^{-1} = 1-x+x^2+O(x^3)$$

I believe O is is supposed to be the error constant.

I started by taking the derivative of the function on the left four times since the function is being equal to the third degree with an error coefficient, but then I have no idea where to go from there.

Can anyone help me.

Thank you

Comment: Both answers are explaining why it is $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$, but  both don't mention, that $O$ is not an error constant, but the symbol of the [Landau-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $\mathcal{O}$. That symbol describes the asymptotic behaviour of "the rest" in the Taylor Expansion. The constant you are mentioning is most likely the $c$ in: If $f(x) =\mathcal{O}(g(x)), (x→∞)$, there is a constant $c$, such that $f(x)=cg(x), (x→∞)$.

Comment: :-) Yeah, we all assume we are taking $x\to0$ @P.Siehr and I personally think its kinda obvious.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The main part of my comment is not  $(x→∞)$, but that you did not write what $\mathcal{O}$ actually means. Therefore I wrote that information in a comment.  OP did state in his question that he "believe[s] O is is supposed to be the error constant." So it is obvious, that it this is not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Algebra is the only thing necessary:

$$\frac1{1+x}=\frac{1+x-x-x^2+x^2+x^3-x^3}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-\frac{x^3}{1+x}$$

And,

$$|x|<\frac12\implies\frac23|x^3|<\left|\frac{x^3}{1+x}\right|<2|x^3|\implies\mathcal O(x^3)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x):=\frac{1}{1+x}$, one version of the Taylor theorem states:

$$ f(x) = f(0)+ f'(0)(x-0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2}(x-0)^2+\int_0^x \frac{f^3(t)}{2!}(x-t)^2 \mathrm{d}t$$

$$ = 1+(-1)x+\frac{2}{2}x^2+R $$

$$ =1-x+x^2+R$$

where

$$ |R| \leq \|f^3\|_{max} \int_0^x \frac{|x-t|^2}{2}\mathrm{d}t$$

$$ \leq \text{Constant} \times x^3$$